# html5: is there a way to prevent children interfering with drag events

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm having a bit of a problem with **html5** drag and drop. I don't see an easy way out of it. Basically i have some "boxes" with some other html elements inside. The parent boxes are draggable and they can be dropped on each other.

I bind `dragover` event on the body to handle drag-drop on the entire page. Problem is, when you drag over the boxes - the event is sometimes triggered on child elements and the parent doesn't get this event at all.

Is there an easy way to prevent this from happening?

Basically i want the dragover event to fire as soon as the mouse is in the area of the target box. I know of a couple of ways of solving this, but they're really ugly and i was wondering if there maybe is something simple.

Thanks for your thoughts

Short version of what i'm doing in code:

```
document.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e) {

    if (e.target.className == 'candrophere')
        // cancel out "e" to allow drop


}, false);
```

But in my case the child elements are taking up almost the entire '.candrophere' box so the event is almost never fired on the correct target (especially when i move the mouse faster)

Comment: You should post the code that is failing so people can help you.

Comment: Updated with some pseudo code without any distractions

Comment: I was able to fix this by simply using the dragover event instead of the dragenter event

Answer (score 19):

The css `pointer-events` rule prevents mouse interaction events from firing on the elements it is applied to, but isn't currently supported by IE (http://caniuse.com/pointer-events).

A workaround I've used for this problem is to add something like

```
.is-drag-in-progress .child-elements
{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

to your CSS, and add the `is-drag-in-progress` class to the `body` element in your `onDragStart` handler (and remove it when the drag ends). This will prevent the child elements from interfering with drag events on the parent element.

Answer (score 2):

Basically my solution is as follows:

Since e.target and e.currentTarget cannot be matched to the parent box most of the time - all that's left to do is to manually check if the e.target is a child of the parent box. There are many ways to do that, but i'm using a custom function. Can't post it here, since it is based on my own framework and won't work without it anyway, but the pseudo-code is as follows:

```
// target is a framework object (much like jquery)
closestDroppableParent = function(target)
{
    // i know that all children in those boxes will not be any deeper than this
    var max_levels = 5;

    while (target && max_levels > 0)
    {
        max_levels--;

        // droppable boxes have data-droptype attribute set so only other boxes with the same attribute
        // can be dropped on them. This check can be done any way you like. You can have a custom class
        // for droppable objects, check for draggable attribute etc...
        // .data() is a framework function that returns the value of the data-* attributes
        if (target.data('droptype'))
            return target;

        // .parent() is a framework function to get parent node
        target = target.parent();
    }

    return null;
}


// drag over event
dragOverEventHandler = function(e)
{
    // convert the element to its closest droppable parent
            // $() is much like jquery
    var closest = closestDroppableParent($(e.target));

    if (closest)
        closest.addClass('draggedOver');
}
```